Equivalent Definitions of Limsup [proof verification]
I've been working on this proof for a few days. While there've been several posts on this, none is not up to my standard for rigor. Below is my attempt, which seems clear to me except for the case when $s = -\infty$.
Note that $\overline{L_s}$ denotes the set of subsequential limits, including possibly $\pm \infty$.  We use the following lemma:

Lemma: Let $s \in \overline{L_s}$. Then $s = \limsup_{n \to \infty} s_n$ iff all $x > s$ strictly bounds above a tail.

Theorem:

Let $(s_n)$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. Then $\limsup_{n \to \infty} s_n = \sup{\overline{L_s}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{m \geq n} s_m$.

Proof:
Put $\sigma_n = \sup_{m \geq n} s_m$ for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, $s = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sigma_n$. It is manifest that $(\sigma_n)$ is a monotonically decreasing sequence.
Assume that $s$ is finite. For each $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, let $N_k$ be the smallest integer such that $(\sigma_{N_k})$ is contained in $N_{\frac{1}{k}}(s)$, and $E_k = \{n \geq N_k : s - \frac{1}{k} < s_n < s + \frac{1}{k}\}$. Fixing $k$, for each $n \geq N_k$, $s_n \leq \sigma_{n} < s + \frac{1}{k}$. Hence if $E_k$ were not infinite, there would be an $m \geq N_k$ such that $n \geq m \implies s_n \leq s - \frac{1}{k}$. But then $s - \frac{1}{k} < \sigma_m$ is an upper bound of $(s_m)$, a contradiction. Choosing $n_k = \min\{n \in E_k : n > n_{k - 1}\}$, we have a subsequence $(s_{n_k})$ satisfying $s - \frac{1}{k} < s_{n_k} < s + \frac{1}{k}$ for every $k$. It follows from the squeeze theorem that $s_{n_k} \to s \implies s \in \overline{L_s}$.
If $s = \infty$, then for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, $\sigma_n = \infty$. Hence $(s_n)$ is not bounded above and has a subsequence tending to $\infty$, so it must be that $\sup{\overline{L_s}} = \infty$.
Now let $x > s$, such that there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ where $x = s + \epsilon$. Then there exists an $N \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $n \geq N \implies \sigma_n - s < \epsilon \implies s_n \leq \sigma_n < x$, and the proof follows from the supplied lemma.

Sorry, this is not too clear. What are you actually trying to prove? What is $L$?

I just fixed the confusing part.

This looks fine to me, perhaps a bit convoluted, but all good. As an exercise, prove that any sequence has at least a limit point, i.e., that $L_s$ is not empty. This will remove the possibility that $s=-\infty$. In fact, this idea of $L_s\neq\varnothing$ can be used for a shorter proof of the theorem.

I don't think this is true though. Consider the sequence $(-n)$, whose set of subsequential limits comprises $-\infty$ alone.

ah, sorry you are right. got confused by the fact that $L_s$ is not a subset of the real line necessarily, but of the extended real line. then the case $s=-\infty$ just implies that for any real number $x$, there are only finitely many terms in the sequence $s_n$ satisfying $s_n\geq x$.

Got it. Thank you!
